# How to add fields and change required fields in moodle signup form?

Tags: php, html, forms, moodle, mustache

I have a moodle project as a developer and i want to change the sign up form to make it simpler.Bascially, i want to remove the username field and replace it with a full name field and add a phone number field that is not mandatory (required) and remove all the other unnecessary fields or at least set them as not required
[image: sign up form current]

I have hid some of the unnecessary features using CSS but i want something more functional, and want to know what files i need to change to make the changes in the backend so that it works as expected when a user signs up.
Any help/advice with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a hook in Moodle core to handle this.

Create a plugin (probably a '[local](https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/local)' plugin) and make sure its lib.php has a function `local_myplugin_extend_signup_form()` (where 'local_myplugin' is the [Frankenstyle](https://moodledev.io/general/development/policies/codingstyle/frankenstyle) name of your plugin).

Within this function, you can use the $mform instance passed in to call functions such as `$mform->addElement()`, `$mform->insertElementBefore()` and `$mform->removeElement()` to modify the existing form.

You may need to use `local_myplugin_post_signup_requests()` to modify the data, so that it matches the expected data from the form (you will need to generate a 'username' field of some kind), as well as using `local_myplugin_validate_extend_signup_form()` to adjust the validation (as the submission normally validates to make sure the username is present).

Comment: Thanks for the response!
This is what i was looking for!
But i noticed that in moodle's own login folder there is a lib.php with the function "core_login_extend_signup_form($mform)". 

can i just add and remove the elements using this function?
also is the username a mandatory field for validation?
i want to just set the email as the username field in the backend.

also that login folder doesn't contain the 'post_signup_requests()' and 'validate_extend_signup_form()' . 
How do i set it up to match a new field i created in the signup form?

Comment: Also, to set if each field is required or not, 
can i just add  or delete a rule in the signup _form.php 
like this one for the email again field to set it as not required?

" $mform->addElement('text', 'email2', get_string('emailagain'), 'maxlength="100" size="25"');
        $mform->setType('email2', core_user::get_property_type('email'));
        $mform->addRule('email2', get_string('missingemail'), 'required', null, 'client');
        $mform->setForceLtr('email2'); "